# How to get datetime format in Angular.js or Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I need one help.i need to generate date time format like php generates using method `date("YmdHis")` using Angular.js or Javascript.Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In a controller:

```
$scope.timestamp = new Date;
```

In the view:

```
{{ timestamp | date: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss' }}
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date.

Comment: i dont need it to display in view.I can only generate inside the controller for other perpose.

Comment: Then look at the linked documentation, you can use `$filter('date')` inside the controller.